# Android FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD turns screen off

Tags: android, screen, keyguard

I have an activity that dismisses the key guard when it receives a screen_on intent. However the screen always turns back off almost immediately after the dismiss key guard flag. If this the intended behavior?